# How to upload an image with the Kaltura JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, kaltura

I'm using the [Kaltura JavaScript API](http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/testmeDoc/index.php) and am trying to upload an image to the server using [the "upload" action from the "uploadToken" service](http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/testmeDoc/index.php?service=uploadToken&action=upload). I keep getting this error:

```
Missing parameter "fileData"
```

I've tried passing the base 64 encoded version of the image as the fileData parameter, and various other values (the file name, the `input.files[0]` value, a readAsArrayBuffer and convert to binary), but am unable to successfully upload an image. In JavaScript, what should "fileData" be set equal to?

Using the [Kaltura Test Console](http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/testme), I'm able to do this successfully, and I can see the network tab in my browser making the *POST* successfully, with the `fileData`. However, in my JavaScript code, the "upload" action from the "uploadToken" service call is reported as a *GET* operation. I'm starting to think this may be a bug with the [Kaltura JavaScript client library](http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/testme/client-libs.php).

Comment: Can you please add you JS code?

Comment: As it turns out, this isn't possible. Here's the response I got directly from Kaltura: "With JS you can't just use the REST api to upload binary files, there's crossdomain requirements for example. To resolve that easily, please use the JS uploader widget available at: https://github.com/kaltura/jQuery-File-Upload"

Answer (score 0):

You can upload files to Kaltura using JavaScript and the HTML5 file API. But you would have to create the http request manually and not use the JS library.
This solution is limited to modern browsers (in case of IE it's IE10+).
To support IE9 and below, you would have to rely on flash.

If you just need to upload images and not large files, then use a server side proxy script that will not be limited by [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).